# read specific lines with sed and declare into separate variables

Tags: bash, sed

I have a script called `envisat_header` which reads specific files and output the result on screen. I tried to read specific lines and declare them into string variables however I would like to avoid running the script for each line:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in $(find ~/ -name '*.N1'); do   
  declare orbitnr=$(envisat_header $i | sed -n -e '38p' | awk '{print $3}')
  declare dateimg=$(envisat_header $i | sed -n -e '39p' | awk '{print substr($3,2); }')
  declare FN_lat=$(envisat_header $i | sed -n -e '70p' | awk '{print $3}')
  declare FN_lon=$(envisat_header $i | sed -n -e '71p' | awk '{print $3}')
done
```

which obviously means to read lines 38,39,70 and 71 of the output. Actually I want a single line like (the `awk` part doesn't really matter):

```
envisat_header $i | sed -n -e '38p;39p;70p;71p'
```

but the problem is I don't know how to declare those lines into separate string variables. could you suggest any alternative ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control over, and/or confidence in the input, you could just use `eval`. However, if the input could contain shell code (by oversight, or because somebody wants to harm you) this is not safe.

```
eval $(envisat_header "$i" |
    awk 'NR==38 { print "orbitnr=" $3 ";"}
        NR==39 { print "dateimg=" substr($3,2) ";"}
        NR==70 { print "FN_lat=" $3 ";"}
        NR==71 { print "FN_lon=" $3 ";"}')
```

The output from the Awk script is a sequence of shell variable assignments. Run it without `eval` to see the generated code.

Notice also how `NR==...` allows you to factor out `sed` entirely. Very often, `sed` | `awk` is [useless](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#grep) and better written entirely in Awk.

Answer (score 3):

Make use of `array`:

```
# assume that `arr` contains 4 words
arr=($(envisat_header $i | sed -n -e '38p;39p;70p;71p'))

w=${arr[0]}
x=${arr[1]}
y=${arr[2]}
z=${arr[3]}
```